# Putting a whole SQL Database into HTML Table

Tags: php, html, mysql

I'm trying to put a whole SQL database into html table. I'm using MySQLi API.
But it just return the first row of the table , and the rest of them just look mess up.Here's my code:

```
            <h1> School Lesson System</h1>

            <?php

                if(isset($_SESSION['u_id'])) {
                    echo "You are logged in \n";
                }
            ?>
            <table border="1">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Lesson_id</td>
                        <td>Teacher</td>
                        <td>Lesson</td>
                        <td>Day</td>
                        <td>Time</td>
                        <td>Classroom</td>
                        <td>Year</td>
                        <td>Curriculum</td>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <?php
                    require_once 'includes/dbh.inc.php';

                    $query = "SELECT * FROM monday";
                    $result = $conn->query($query);
                    $rows = $result->num_rows;
                    for ( $j = 0; $j < $rows; ++$j) {
                        $result->data_seek($j);
                        $row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
                    echo "<tr>";
                        echo "<td>" . $row['Lesson_id']. "</td>";
                         echo "<td>". $row['Teacher']. "</td>";
                         echo "<td>" .$row['Lesson']. "</td>";
                         echo "<td>" . $row['Day']. "</td>";
                         echo "<td>". $row['Time']. "</td>";
                         echo "<td>". $row['Classroom']. "</td>";
                         echo "<td>". $row['Year']. "</td>";
                         echo "<td>". $row['Curriculum']. "</td>";
                     echo "</tr>";
                echo"</tbody>";
            echo"</table>";
                    }


include_once 'footer.php';
?>
```

Any solution for this ????

Comment: Instead of looping with `for`, just do `while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {`, that's the standard way of fetching rows.

Comment: You have a table called 'monday'? I'm afraid you have bigger problems that need to be addressed!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.Use `while` instead of `for` loop

2.don't close `<tbody>` and `<table>` inside loop (which is the main problem)

3.I am unable to see `session_start();` in your code, while you are using `SESSION` in your code.So please check and if you don't have ***then add that on top of the page.***

Do like below:-

```
<?php
require_once 'includes/dbh.inc.php';

$query = "SELECT * FROM monday";
$result = $conn->query($query);

while($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
    echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['Lesson_id']. "</td>";
        echo "<td>". $row['Teacher']. "</td>";
        echo "<td>" .$row['Lesson']. "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['Day']. "</td>";
        echo "<td>". $row['Time']. "</td>";
        echo "<td>". $row['Classroom']. "</td>";
        echo "<td>". $row['Year']. "</td>";
        echo "<td>". $row['Curriculum']. "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</tbody>";
echo "</table>";
include_once 'footer.php';
?>
```

Note:-

Table names like `Monday` is not good at all. It will be fruitful name which describes it's purpose itself like `users(list of users)`,`logs(track record of different activities)`...etc.

Comment: Actually the table Monday is meant that all the lesson_id, teacher, classroom .... that happen on monday. But if you can give me a better name , I appreciate that

Answer (score 2):

That's because you close tbody and table tag inside for loop.

```
       echo"</tbody>";
       echo"</table>";
```

move this two lines outside the for.

Answer (score 1):

Change that :

```
<?php
                    require_once 'includes/dbh.inc.php';

                    $query = "SELECT * FROM monday";
                    $result = $conn->query($query);
                    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                    echo "<tr>";
                        echo "<td>" . $row['Lesson_id']. "</td>";
                         echo "<td>". $row['Teacher']. "</td>";
                         echo "<td>" .$row['Lesson']. "</td>";
                         echo "<td>" . $row['Day']. "</td>";
                         echo "<td>". $row['Time']. "</td>";
                         echo "<td>". $row['Classroom']. "</td>";
                         echo "<td>". $row['Year']. "</td>";
                         echo "<td>". $row['Curriculum']. "</td>";
                     echo "</tr>";

                    }
  echo"</tbody>";
                echo"</table>";
```

Comment: it's not lol. Actual problem what OP is facing is not because of `for` loop, it's because `</tbody></table>` written inside `for` loop which makes the whole table distorted. `while` loop is just an enhancement in coding, but it will not going to solve the actual problem of distorted table. If you patiently compare with other answer then you will found that not only your answer is incorrect, but also lack of explanation that why OP have to do this.An answer serve future visitors too,So it need to  have  an explanation.Change your code to make it correct and your down-vote will removed for-sure.

Answer (score 0):

Create a class file for connecting the database

```
  class DBConnUtil {
 private $mysqli;
 function __construct() {
    $this->open_connection();
}

private function open_connection() {    // function to connect database;
        $this->mysqli = new mysqli(DB_SERVER,DB_USER,DB_PASS,DB_NAME);
        if ($this->mysqli->connect_error) {
            die('Error : ('. $this->mysqli->connect_errno .') '. $this->mysqli->connect_error);
        }
        $this->mysqli->set_charset("utf8");
}
public function run_query ($queryString) {
    $result=$this->mysqli->query($queryString);

    if (!$result) {
        trigger_error('Wrong SQL: ' . $queryString . ' Error: ' . $this->mysqli->error, E_USER_ERROR);                                                                  
    }
    $this->close_connection();
    return $result;
}



private function close_connection() {
        $this->mysqli->close();
}
```

}

Then another class file Lesson.php. Use the database column as private variable i it..Then write a function fetchData() like this.

```
    public function fetchData() {
    $dbConn = new DBConnUtil(); //name of the database class mention 
    before..
    $queryString = "select * from tablename ";
    $result = $dbConn->run_query($queryString);
    $rows_returned = $result->num_rows;

    $categorydata = array();
    while($rows = $result->fetch_object()){
   $categorydata[] =  $rows;
    }
    $result->free();
   return $categorydata;

   }
```

then use foreach statement to print it..

Comment: Why would a wrapper make it easier? Why isn't the direct interface good enough? In my experience, a wrapper like these only creates more headaches than it solves.